# Architectural/best-practices question about generics

Tags: c#, design-patterns, generics, architecture

I'm working my way through 'head first design patterns' and want to use this in practice immediately.
I'm writing a piece of code that connects an application with other applications. In fact, I need to generate an e-mail containing an XML file and send it via e-mail. But other stuff might be required in the future.

Thus, I identified 'the things that change':
- The data for the transmission
- The means of transmitting (could be e-mail, but could be FTP or webservice for another data-exchange)

So, I:
- Created an abstract class DataObject
- Created an interface ITransmissionMethod
- Created an dataExchange abstract class:

```
  abstract class DataExchange<T,U>
    {
        private T DataObject;
        private U SendMethod;
    }
```

And SendViaMail is like

```
class SendViaMail : ISendMethod<System.Net.Mail.Attachment>
{
    public override void Send(System.Net.Mail.Attachment dataItem)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Now - I can create classes like:

```
class MyExchange : DataExchange<MyDataObject,SendViaMail> { }
```

What do you think about this approach? Now what I would really like to do is Create an abstract method in DataExchange that should look something like

```
private abstract [the type of the T in ISendMethod<T>] PrepareObjectForSending(T dataObject) {
}
```

Visual Studio would force me to implement a method like:

```
private abstract System.Net.Mail.Attachment PrepareObjectForSendingMyDataObject dataObject) {
// Serialize XML file and make it into attachment object
}
```

Wouldn't that be sweet? But what do you guys think about this approach? In the future, people can create new dataObjects and new sendmethods and the code would still work. What I've been trying to do is: program against interface and extract changing parts. How about it?

Comment: Seems a little contrived to me. I'd probably just use an `enum` for the sending method. And you wouldn't need a generic to keep the data object. IMHO this is a good example of overly complex code for its own sake.

Comment: I halfway agree with Yuck. Just because something *might* change down the road doesn't mean you should build out architecture to support that. I would suggest having the system set up so that migrating to that architecture if it becomes necessary isn't impossible, but don't build it all out.

Comment: From what you've written here, it's hard to see what use of generics buys you. You might be better off with base classes/interfaces for DataObject and SendMethod.  Only use generics when it makes things easier.

Comment: Thanks Harper and Yuck - "Just because something might change down the road doesn't mean you should build out architecture to support that." that's an interesting point. Reading the book made me think I had to make everything as dynamic as possible, but It's a good thing to point out that you don't want to make things too complex if not necessary. Thanks, I'll scrap this design and make life easier for me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That would work, but you could separate concerns even more. Here is just another version - make DataExchange to be very simple and delegate real work to workers:

```
class DataExchange<TDataObject, TTransmissionObject>
{
    IConverter<TDataObject, TTransmissionObject> conterver;
    ISendMethod<TTransmissionObject> sender;

    public Send(TDataObject dataObject)
    {
        TTransmissionObject tro = conterver.Convert(dataObject);
        sender.Send(tro);
    }
}
```

Converts would just convert data objects to objects suitable for transmission:

```
class DataToAttachmentConverter : IConverter<DataObject, Attachment>
{
    Attachment Convert(DataObject) { }
}
class DataToXmlConverter : IConverter<DataObject, XmlDocument>
{
    XmlDocument Convert(DataObject) { }
}
```

Senders would only send.

```
class MailSender : ISendMethod<Attachment>
{
    void Send(Attachment) {}
}
class FtpPublisher : ISendMethod<XmlDocument>
{
    void Send(XmlDocument) {}
}
```

Putting all together:

```
var exchanges = new [] {
      new DataExchange<DataObject, Attachment>( new DataToAttachmentConverter(), new MailSender()),
      new DataExchange<DataObject, XmlDocument>( new DataToXmlConverter(), new FtpPublisher())
};

foreach(var ex in exchanges)
    ex.Send(dataObject); //send as an attachent and put to ftp site.
```